# Any idea why does my published Android app instantly close when I open it?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

My app works in the Android emulator and on a tethered device. But after I published the app, downloaded it on my Android device, the app closes immediately when I open it.

I even tried to create another Google Play app profile and upload the same APK with the same result?

How should I approach fixing this? Thanks!

Comment: Does it crash with a message?

Comment: I just get a prompt asking me if I want to open the app again.

Comment: Attach `Crashlytics` or any similar crash tracking tools to track your app on the production version. Get the stack trace and post it here. No one can help if you have nothing to show

Comment: @TamHuynh I’ll try that. thanks

Comment: Show the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the fabric.io kit to your android gradle file and get the crash report to your mail.

Follow this [link](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) to go through the Crashlytics Installation process via Gradle.

Answer (score 6):

you could try integrating a library which would help you get various insights about the crash.

[Instabug](http://instabug.com) is a bug and crash reporting service which automatically records and reports any crashes that occur to your app.

Reports include the following data:

- Code stack trace
- Network and console logs
- Device details
- Reproduction steps of the crash

It takes a line of code to integrate the SDK.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.